# how to set background color animation?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

When I click on the button, I animate the button to change the image via:

```
@IBAction func btn_lockdragg(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        
        if sender.isSelected == true {
            
            UIView.transition(with: sender as UIView, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
                
                sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "lock"), for: .normal)
                        }, completion: nil)
          
            
        } else {
            
            
            UIView.transition(with: sender, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
                
                sender.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "lock.open"), for: .normal)
                        }, completion: nil)
        }
        




}
```

Please how can I change background color of animation? I still need the background color of the button.

[image]

Comment: What's the background color of animation? Animation doesn't have colors.

Comment: When I click the button, the background color changes to dark gray, the button rotates, and then the background color changes back.

Comment: The background color of what?

Comment: Button background color

Comment: Have you tried changing the `backgroundColor` property of the button?

Comment: Yes of course. Background color, fill, stroke.

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate that though, are you modifying the background color somewhere else?

Comment: Yes in Storyboard. For example, if you try to call sender.backgroundColor = .red before UIView.transition, the background color of the animation does not change

Comment: I see the same occurs with any type of animation. Even if UIView is a plain unicolor UIView. I've tried to set buttonToBeCurled.layer.shadowOpacity to 0.0 or buttonToBeCurled.layer.shadowColor to UIColor.clear.cgColor to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. For the button, the following must be set: Type: Custom, Style: Default and Background: Default